# The search for CpG islands in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I was looking for a algorithm in R for finding CpG islands. I have not found a particular one, so I decided to make my own. The algorithm in question comes from an article by Gardiner-garden and Frommer (any Google search can find this article available for reading), and the main rules are:

1. A CpG island is defined as a region of at least 200 bp,
2. “GC content” or the proportion of GC dinucleotides greater than 50%,
3. The observed to expected CpG ratio (O/E) greater than 0.6. This is calcuated with the formula:

   Obs/Exp CpG = Number of CpG * N / (Number of C * Number of G)

with N the number of nucleotides in the segment under consideration.

I did not get far with this idea, because I lack the knowledge in programming for this, but I found the steps for this algorithm and how it should work:

1. The location of each 'CG' in the genome sequence is identified, along with the number of nucleotides since the previous 'CG' and the numbers of C's and G's.
2. The total number of nucleotides lets us compute the length of a
   putative island, and the C and G counts let us compute the GC% and
   O/E scores.
3. An array of successive CpGs that might belong to an island is built up according to these rules:

`a.`  We start with the first CpG in the genome and add subsequent CpGs to
    the array one by one (sliding the right edge forward).

`b.`  Each time we add a CpG on the right:

`1b)` If length is < 200, we keep going (add another to the right).
        Otherwise the length criteria is met and we evaluate %GC and O/E.

`2b)` If all three criteria are met, we make a note that our putative island looks good and keep going (try to build a bigger island).    If all three criteria were met before we added this CpG, but now %GC and O/E are no longer met, we use this CpG as the start of a new putative island and print out the island from the previous iteration.

`3b)` If %GC and O/E weren't met before and still aren't met, we remove the first CpGs from the array (sliding the left edge forward) until the length is < 200.

`4b)` If we reach the end of the sequence and our putative island meets the criteria, print it out.

A sample sequence can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/3p8H7tcg).

My effort thus far:

```
a=lapply(x, function(vec){
  x <- gregexpr("gc", vec, perl = TRUE)
  res <- sum(attr(x[[1]], "match.length"))
  res
})


b=lapply(x, function(vec){
  x <- gregexpr("g", vec, perl = TRUE)
  res <- regmatches(vec, x)
  res
}) 


c=lapply(x, function(vec){
  x <- gregexpr("c", vec, perl = TRUE)
  res <- regmatches(vec, x)
  res
})
```

These are the functions I made to find "GC", "G" or "C" in the sequence. With this function I split the sequence into 500 bits:

```
x=split(seq_GC, (0:nrow(seq_GC) %/% 500))
```

so its easier to handle a big sequence.

If someone could help, I would be very thankful.

EDIT 1:

After looking around more I found that these above steps for the algorithm are in fact something called a sliding window algorithm. Here, on Stackoverflow I found many samples of a sliding window algorithm for R. This might be the solution for this algorithm, if there are some changes made. The code below:

```
slide_function <- function(data, window, step){
  total <- length(data)
  spots <- seq(from=1, to=(total-window), by=step)
  result <- vector(length = length(spots))
  for(i in 1:length(spots)){

    result[i] <- 

  }
  return(result)
}
```

has to have more conditions, but also be able to save the position of each GC in the sequence.